# how to mount NTFS partition image on linux from file?

Tags: c, linux, ntfs

i need to mount at least for read access NTFS-based partition image on linux from a file. File is binary copy of a partition. Is there any libraries or resources for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It'd be the same process as mounting an ISO image: use the loopback interface but specify NTFS/ntfs-3g as the FS type instead of iso9660.

Example [here for ISO images](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/857/mount-an-iso-file-in-linux/), but trivially modifiable to ntfs images.